# Zero Voltage in a power semiconductor chip

Tags: power-electronics, semiconductors, igbt, powermosfet, chip-design

In an ON-mode silicon IGBT chip operating within a real power module, is the collector contact fixed at 0 V or emitter?
What about Power SiC MOSFET?
[enter link description here](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IFS75B12N3E4_B31-DS-v02_00-en_de.pdf?fileId=db3a3043293a15c4012946144f0d5440)

Comment: Huh??  You're going to have to be a lot more specific.  Give an example with a link to a datasheet and a schematic showing what you are asking about.  Power modules are general purpose and much depends on the application and specific implementation.

Comment: What is a "real power module"? Can you link to a datasheet? (Add the info into your question - not in the comments.)

Comment: @Transistor, the datasheet link has been added.

Answer (score 1):

IGBTs are only available in NPN type, so to make something like a bridge you have to use two of them. Typically the lower one(s) will have the emitter common with the negative rail and the upper one(s) will have the collector common with the positive rail. From [this](http://www.irf.com/electronics/topology-fundamentals) Infineon web page:

[image]

The same is true of MOSFETs when only N-channel types are used. For practical reasons that's the case with almost all high voltage H-bridge, 3-phase bridges, and half-bridges. At lower voltages, such as 12VDC or 24VDC, it may become attractive to use P-channel MOSFETs for the upper switches, which allows the sources of those transistors to be tied to the positive rail, which in turn simplifies the gate drive circuitry.